# Excel calculating percentage number occurs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet for a skills matrix. Individuals rank their skill knowledge from 1-4.

I have been asked to write the percentage of employees that have chosen 3 or 4 for their knowledge on each skill.

I have currently written the percentage in alongside but would like this to be automated so that when someone improved their knowledge of a skill subsequent columns can reflect this to show my progress in the improvements.

I pretty much want a formula that says if cell shows 3 or 4 return 25% for each (I have 4 employees) and if 1 or 2 return 0% and to stack up so if 3 people rank 3 or 4 it shows 75% in the cell.

Comment: please share some sample data, your problem isn't really clear now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will work with any number of employees ...

[image]

The Cell C2 contains this equation (and is filled down for the rest of Column C) ...

`=IF(B2>=3,1,0)/COUNTA($A$2:$A$10)`

and Cell E3 is just a sum of Column C ... `=SUM(C2:C10)`